# Haskell - Assigning a value to user defined types

Tags: haskell, user-defined-types

**Question**

I have defined a user defined type as

```
type asd = [(Char,Int)]
```

How can i assigin a value to a type `asd` such as `asd= [("Hello",1)]` **(Not in run time)** to keep hard code a value in source code

is this possible ? , becouse there is no *variable* concept in functional programming

Comment: You can't. Haskell is static. Why do you think you need to?

Comment: Type names need to be capitalized, plus your types don't match up. Did you mean something like `type Asd = [(String, Int)]`?

Comment: Also, you just defined an *alias*  for `[(Char,Int)]`, similiar to C's `typedef`. If you want to create an unique new type, use the `data` keyword instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are defining a constant. An example would be:

```
-- A type of lists of pairs
type ASD = [(String,Int)]

-- A value of type ASD
asd :: ASD
asd = [("Hello", 1)]
```

That is, you just *declare* what the value of `asd` is.